# Get all the Emails and contacts of gmail by gdata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdata

I am making an application to get all the email and contacts of the gmail in my application . I managed to get gdata in my project by gadata-objective c-client-1.11.0.a.I googled for it but doesn't get much from it. Can any one help me with it by providing an example or tutorial as i am new to the iphone programming....
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I done for getting contacts for logged in user.I loaded them in the table with contact name and email id of that contact.You try out this link for setting up gdata xcode in your project.
http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/
After integrating them in your project open up gdata contacts example and follow the method
- (IBAction)getFeedClicked:(id)sender
in that they called for getting group contact, but you give
- (void)fetchAllContacts
then you add the methods in your code what are all needed for that method, then at last you can get contacts entries.it is a array then you can load them in the table.

Comment: Can you please tell me where i can find example of gdata contacts?